# Existe algum pattern relacionado à tipagem ou não de valores no retorno de JSON em API's?

Tags: json, design-pattern

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma problemática envolvida em passar os valores das chaves em JSON todos como string ou se existe alguma justificativa para manter sempre os tipos originais do dado?

Minha pergunta se baseia no fato de que há um tempo tive alguns **problemas com a passagem de valores em Float**, especificamente em PHP com o json_encode, e em um tópico do SO havia achado uma explicação do problema, que inclusive foi a solução (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981409/php7-1-json-encode-float-issue). Entretanto **passei a sempre passar todos os valores float de um JSON como String** no desenvolvimento de API's para evitar esse tipo de problema.

**Existe alguma recomendação/justificativa referente a tipagem ou não dos valores em JSON ao desenvolver uma API? Ou realmente é algo "irrelevante" e fica a mercê do desenvolvedor definir o padrão que lhe seja útil?**

Pergunto isso pois já tive que consumir API's com diversos tipos de padrões diferentes, seja passando todos os valores como String, ou mantendo a tipagem original dos valores, algumas até realizando a mescla das duas situações (algumas chaves com valores inteiros/decimais como string outras mantendo a tipagem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Padrões dizem respeito a como trabalhar com os objetos e arquitetura do sistema e não de um tipo de objeto em específico.
Vai depender do problema que você está lidando, como você fez a arquitetura do seu sistema e o que a documentação do conjunto de ferramentas que você esta usando sugere.

**Existe alguma recomendação/justificativa referente a tipagem ou não dos valores em JSON ao desenvolver uma API? Ou realmente é algo "irrelevante" e fica a mercê do desenvolvedor definir o padrão que lhe seja útil?**

Vai depender da sua arquitetura, se houver a utilização de algum framework, normalmente ele sugere, e isso vai seguir algum modelo arquitetural, preferencialmente.

Comment: Tinha imaginado que fosse isso realmente, considerando que não teve outras respostas, suponho que de fato não tenha um "padrão recomendado" pra isso. Obrigado.